# What does a delay(0) actually do?

Tags: delay

I've seen some code where the developers add `delay(0)`, it doesnt make sense, what does it do? Delay with zero milliseconds, why?

```
bool DFRobotDFPlayerMini::waitAvailable(unsigned long duration){
  unsigned long timer = millis();
  if (!duration) {
    duration = _timeOutDuration;
  }
  while (!available()){
    if (millis() - timer > duration) {
      return false;
    }
    delay(0);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Delay (traditionally) has two functions that it performs:

1. Wait for a period
2. Yield processing to other threads through the `yield()` weak symbol.

By using a `delay(0)` the author thinks they are saying "I don't want to delay here, but if anything is using the `yield()` function it can run now."

However, that is *not* correct.

The code for `delay()` in the AVR core looks like this:

```cpp
void delay(unsigned long ms) 
{
    uint32_t start = micros();

    while (ms > 0) {
        yield();
        while ( ms > 0 && (micros() - start) >= 1000) {
            ms--;
            start += 1000;
        }
    }   
}
```

You can see that, as well as delaying for a period, `yield()` is regularly called. However that only ever happens if `ms` is greater than 0. If you pass `0` as the delay length then the `delay()` function essentially does nothing at all.

Now it *could* be that an earlier version of the core had `yield()` always being called even with `ms==0`, but the current version doesn't. Maybe this is a hangup from an old coding style.  But for the current core if you want to yield you must explicitly call `yield()` or delay for *at least one millisecond*.

Comment: esp8266 `delay` has yield with 0 delay and esp32 `delay` directly calls vTaskDelay in SDK. The mded cores call RTOS thread sleep.

Comment: Is there anything to yield *to* in the AVR core?

Comment: @AndreKR Not in the core, no. `yield()` is defined "weak" so that you (or a library) can override it to implement a form of crude cooperative threading.

Comment: Yepp this is exactly what i saw when looking at the delay() method. That made it more confusing. So it does nothing since milliseconds is lower then zero.

Comment: Not "lower than" but "not greater than". Subtle difference.

Comment: @Majenko Sorry =P